# How to make a circle breadcrumb with only CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

Has anyone seen a available css3 solution to implement the above? I'd like to find a way without requiring images and also not rewrite something that others have likely already solved well. Anyone know of any existing solutions?

Comment: Where did you find the image? Have you tried anything yourself? Have a look at CSS `border-radius`

Comment: Have you tried to write a repeated radial gradient of a fixed size? If not, try it. Including vendor prefixes, the final result *might* actually have a bigger size than a base64-encoded data-URI.

Comment: You can use border-radius to make an element circular and inset box shadows to give the effect of depth

Comment: @RobW A [`repeating-radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-radial-gradient) "repeats the color stops", not the gradients. But maybe it would work with [multiple background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds) gradients (instead of list).

Comment: @feeela "repeated" in my hint refers to the `background-repeat` property, and "fixed size" refers to `background-size`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simple using **CSS3**'s `border-radius` property:

[image]

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ojejuf/6/edit)**

**[LIVE DEMO with a bit of CSS3 anim + jQuery](http://jsbin.com/ojejuf/8/edit)**

**HTML**

```
  <span class="btnz">
    <span class="active"></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.btnz>span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background:#C0CCD7;
  border-radius:7px;
  border:1px solid #C0CCD7;
  border-top:1px solid #9DA7AF;
  margin:0 3px;
}
.btnz>span.active{
  background: #63C000;
  border: 1px solid #5FAF0E;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #39660F;
}
```

**More info here:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: I don't quite like the rendering of the border on those, so I edited your jsbin to use a box-shadow instead (as suggested in my answer). I think the rendering is nicer. Also I've added an extra highlight on the active one, just to show off ;) http://jsbin.com/ojejuf/4/edit

Comment: @jods you're missing `cursor:pointer;` and other crazy stuff: http://jsbin.com/ojejuf/7/edit ;)

Comment: I see you've worked a lot since I posted my comment. Even included (one) vendor prefix... Nice job. ;)

Comment: @jods hehehe ;) you too nice job!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have no ready-made implementation to suggest. But it shouldn't be too hard to achieve on modern browsers.

Create just a <div> (or any element, maybe a link <a>) per dot.

To make it round: use `border-radius`. By making the rounded corners radius half the height/width of the div you will get a circle.

The top (on inactive) or bottom (on active) 3d lighting effect can very simply be emulated with a `box-shadow: inset ...`.

From what I see in your image, pick the correct colors and that's it, pretty much.

Answer (score -3):

Canvas.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial

Canvas canvas canvas canvas canvas.

EDIT: OK, after all the downvotes, here is an alternative answer....SVG.  :D

EDIT EDIT: How about inline list elements with no text?

EDIT EDIT EDIT: Seriously, border-radius is a pretty good way to go.

Comment: What part of "only css" was unclear? Your answer shouts "canvas", without even explaining why it ought to be used instead of CSS.

Comment: And please no, don't use a canvas for something as simple as that. You'll end up with much more code and you'll lose the ability to easily handle clicks and mouse-overs.

Comment: You're all right of course.  How about this?

    <li>&nbsp;</li>