# creating a line breadcrumb purely in CSS

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there was a way to create this style of breadcrumb: http://www.lumosity.com/app/v5/personalization/memory

with only CSS. I've looked online for any articles but all the ones I found were for triangle breadcrumbs. If you guys know any articles please share.

I found a stackoverflow that had the answer if anyone else was looking for it. 
[Creating CSS3 Circles connected by lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642308/creating-css3-circles-connected-by-lines)

I just had to change the words i was searching a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?
http://jsfiddle.net/8u2Bp/9/

Is purely css, so no code for actually changing div or page or whatever.

For this effect, you have to play with the `li:before` and the `li:after` tags, and I used the `css counter` for the steps as well.

For more info about hte css counter, check this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters

Hope it helps.