# How to get breadcrumb with circle and lines?

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

This is my code, I have created a breadcrumb and instead of "circle" text, I want circles over there. When I am doing through css it is messing up the code. How can i get it in html so that instead of "circle" text, Circles should come .Please refer to the image for the reference

[image]

```css
 /* Steps progressbar */
        .steps-progress-bar {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            overflow: hidden;
            /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
            counter-reset: step;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .steps-progress-bar li {
            list-style-type: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            width: 25%;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .steps-progress-bar li p {
            color: #b9b9b9;
        }

        /*progressbar connectors*/
        .steps-progress-bar li:after {
            content: '';
            width: 100%;
            height: 3px;
            background: #eeeeee;
            position: absolute;
            left: -50%;
            top: 20px;
            z-index: -1
        }

        .steps-progress-bar li:first-child:after {
            /*connector not needed before the first step*/
            content: none;
        }

        /*marking active/completed steps green*/
        /*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
        .steps-progress-bar li.active:before,
        .steps-progress-bar li.active:after {
            background: #0072DC;
            color: white;
        }

        .steps-progress-bar li.active p {
            color: #0072DC
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-nav">
            <h1 style="text-align:center">Share your Idea</h1>
            <ul class="steps-progress-bar">
                <li id="first-step" class= "active">
                    <p>circle</p> <p>Idea</p>
                </li>
                <li id="second-step" >
                    <p>circle</p> <p>Details</p>
                </li>
                <li id="third-step" class="">
                   <p>circle</p> <p>Contact Info</p>
                </li>
                <li id="fourth-step" class="">
                    <p>circle</p>   <p>Submission</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: please check ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609665/creating-a-line-breadcrumb-purely-in-css

Comment: Thanks, but with before and after it is messing up my code in AEM

Comment: @user15895653 how is before & after messing up your code?