# Creating connected circles

Tags: html, css

I need to create this image:

[image]

It contains circles attached with lines. I drew in the red boxes to show that they are divs because when it's displayed on mobile it should look like this:

[image]

I've tried doing [what this post says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642308/creating-css3-circles-connected-by-lines) but it doesn't work for me since the li's woudln't be in the same div.

This is my code:

```css
.steps {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.step-1,
.step-2,
.step-3,
.step-4 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <div class="step-1">
    <div class="step-image">
      <img src="step1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="step-title">Measure Your Space</div>
    <div class="step-number">1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step-2">
    <div class="step-image">
      <img src="step2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="step-title">Your Kitchen is Designed</div>
    <div class="step-number">2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="step-3">
    <div class="step-image">
      <img src="step3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="step-title">Your Materials are Shipped</div>
    <div class="step-number">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="step-4">
    <div class="step-image">
      <img src="step4.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="step-title">Start contruction of your dream kitchen</div>
    <div class="step-number">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I create the circles with lines connecting them?

Comment: are you able to produce responsive code which looks like your desired picture on mobile, and looks like your desired picture (except missing the lines) on desktop?  If so, post that, and it will be easier for us to help you by just adding in the lines where needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following solution is for version with lines.
To remove lines place `content: none;` under media-query.

```css
section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  margin: .5em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .5em;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: silver;
}

a:before, a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 1em;
  z-index: -1;
}

a:before {
  margin-left: -1px;
  left: -.5em;
  right: 50%;
}

a:after {
  margin-right: -1px;
  left: 50%;
  right: -.5em;
}

section:first-child a:before,
section:last-child a:after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <a>1</a>
    </div>
  </section><section>
    <div>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <a>2</a>
    </div>
  </section><section>
    <div>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <a>3</a>
    </div>
  </section><section>
    <div>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <a>4</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample, with a minimal markup, and for the marker and line the `::after` and `::before` pseudo element is used (starting from the 2:nd position)

```css
div.connected {
  counter-reset: num;
}
div.connected div {
  float: left;
  width: calc(25% - 22px);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 80px 0 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/60/f00) no-repeat top 10px center;
}
div.connected div::after {
  display: block;
  counter-increment: num;
  content: counter(num);
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.connected div ~ div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 1.5em + 22px);
  right: calc(50% + 0.75em);
  height: 1px;
  background-color: gray;
  bottom: calc(.75em + 10px);
  z-index: -1;
}
div.connected span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  div.connected div {
    width: calc(50% - 22px);
  }
  div.connected div:nth-child(n+3) {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  div.connected div:nth-child(3)::before {
    display: none;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="connected">
  <div>
    <span>Some text here</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Some text here</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Some text here</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Some text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is an updated version that solves the misalignment when an item have longer text

```css
div.connected {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-reset: num;
}
div.connected div {
  float: left;
  width: calc(25% - 22px);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 80px 0 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/60/f00) no-repeat top 10px center;
}
div.connected div::after {
  display: block;
  counter-increment: num;
  content: counter(num);
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 0.75em - 1px);
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
div.connected div ~ div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 1.5em + 22px);
  right: calc(50% + 0.75em);
  height: 1px;
  background-color: gray;
  bottom: calc(.75em + 10px);
  z-index: -1;
}
div.connected span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  div.connected div {
    width: calc(50% - 22px);
  }
  div.connected div:nth-child(n+3) {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  div.connected div:nth-child(3)::before {
    display: none;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="connected">
  <div>
    <span>Some text here</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Some text here</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Some long long long text here</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Some text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated, being asked how to move text below the circles, so here is one way (see notes in CSS)

*Note, since absolute positioning is used for the connectors/circles, and as longer text can wrap, one might need to adjust the bottom distance (`50px`) using the existing @media query.*

```css
div.connected {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-reset: num;
}

div.connected div {
  float: left;
  width: calc(25% - 22px);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
  
  /* padding: 80px 0 10px 0;   changed  */
  padding: 120px 0 10px 0;
  
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/60/f00) no-repeat top 10px center;
}

div.connected div::after {
  display: block;
  counter-increment: num;
  content: counter(num);
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 0.75em - 1px);
  
  /* bottom: 10px;   changed  */
  bottom: 50px;

  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

div.connected div~div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 1.5em + 22px);
  right: calc(50% + 0.75em);
  height: 1px;
  background-color: gray;
  
  /* bottom: calc(.75em + 10px);   changed  */
  bottom: calc(.75em + 50px);
  
  z-index: -1;
}

div.connected span {
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.connected div {
    width: calc(50% - 22px);
  }
  div.connected div:nth-child(n+3) {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  div.connected div:nth-child(3)::before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="connected">
  <div>
    <span>Some text here</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Some text here</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Some long long long text here</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Some text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is responsive and the accepted one isn't. Am I missing something ?

Comment: This seems to have [a mis-alignment problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzVur.png) (same as my answer), when there's a long text inside the span.

Comment: @JohnBupit Updated with a version that doesn't misalign

Comment: @altoids Updated with a version that does solve the misalignment issue

Comment: @LGSon How can i move the text below connected circle

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Given the markup you have, one simple solution would be to align the horizontal line (the `:after` pseudo-element of `.step-number`) relative to `.step-#` div. Here's how:

```
.step-1,
.step-2,
.step-3,
.step-4 {
  ...
  /* Set position of step divs to be relative. */
  position: relative;
}

.step-number:after {
  /* Absolutely position this to the bottom center of step-#.
     15px is the radius of step-number.
     A 100% width, and a 50% left expands the line's
     length to the center of the next step-#. */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;

  ...
}

.step-number {
  /* A fixed width of 30px allows us to correctly position the line. */
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  ...
}
```

```css
.step-number {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px #AAA solid;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
/* 
Absolutely position this to the bottom center of step-#.
15px is the radius of step-number.

A 100% width, and a 50% left expands the line's
length to the center of the next step-#.
*/

.step-number:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #AAA;
}
/* Hide the line after the last step */

.step-4 .step-number:after {
  display: none;
}
.steps {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.step-title {
  min-height: 80px;
}
.step-1,
.step-2,
.step-3,
.step-4 {
  width: 22%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  /* Set position of step divs to be relative. */
  position: relative;
  border: 1px #FAA solid;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .step-number:after {
    content: none;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <div class="step-1">
    <div class="step-image">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="step-title">Measure Your Space</div>
    <div class="step-number">1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step-2">
    <div class="step-image">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="step-title">Your Kitchen is Designed</div>
    <div class="step-number">2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="step-3">
    <div class="step-image">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="step-title">Your Materials are Shipped</div>
    <div class="step-number">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="step-4">
    <div class="step-image">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="step-title">Start contruction of your dream kitchen</div>
    <div class="step-number">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To keep up with small screens, you can add a media query to hide the horizontal lines, once the `.step-#`s span to multiple rows.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .step-number:after {
    content: none;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution because it uses the HTML code I added in the problem. There is a problem with responsive design though. You can see the number 4 not properly aligning http://screencast.com/t/NqWNyWxVuT

Comment: This is happening because you seem to have `vertical-align: top` on your `.step-#`s. Two quick work-arounds would be to, either changing it to `vertical-align: bottom` (and live with the _mis-aligned_ images), or adding a `min-height` to your `.step-title`. See latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.steps {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.step-1,
.step-2,
.step-3,
.step-4 {
  width: 90px;
  height:200px;
  float: left;
  border:2px solid #ff0000;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  margin:5px;
  z-index:999;
}
img{
  width:50%;
  height:50px;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:10px
  }
.step-number{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 43%;
    padding: 4px;
  z-index:999;
  }
hr{
  position: absolute;
    width: 282px;
    height: 1px;
    right: 53px;
    bottom: 23px;
    z-index: 990;
 }
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <div class="step-1">
    <div class="step-image">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElI1w.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="step-title">Measure Your Space</div>
    <div class="step-number">1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step-2">
    <div class="step-image">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElI1w.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="step-title">Your Kitchen is Designed</div>
    <div class="step-number">2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="step-3">
    <div class="step-image">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElI1w.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="step-title">Your Materials are Shipped</div>
    <div class="step-number">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="step-4">
    <div class="step-image">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElI1w.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="step-title">Start contruction of your dream kitchen</div>
    <div class="step-number">4</div>
    <hr/>
  </div>
</div>
```