# HTML: Table row highlight

Tags: css, html

I followed [Creating CSS3 Circles connected by lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642308/creating-css3-circles-connected-by-lines) to create circles-connected-by-lines as row elements of a HTML Table. I have also enabled row highlighting on hover.

My code can be found here:

```
`https://codepen.io/bhaktaonline/pen/XzoVPr`
```

The problem is when I hover and the row is highlighted, I am loosing the lines that are connecting the circles.  (in this case, the line connecting the two circles vanishes in the highight color).

Appreciate some insight on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is a result of the negative value you have specified for the `z-index` property of the *pseudo-element* `li::before`.

Remove this `z-index` property declared on `li::before`, instead declare a `z-index` value on the *list items* (`li.data`), since it is a *positioned element already* (`position: relative`), a `z-index` property value will apply, .eg:

```
li.data {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    background: dodgerblue;
    margin: 0 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    /* additional */
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
ul.bigger {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

ul.highlight-active li.active::before {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  background: green;
}

li.data {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: dodgerblue;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  /* additional */
  z-index: 1;
}

li.ack {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: MediumSeaGreen;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: .9em;
  left: -4em;
  width: 4em;
  height: .2em;
  background: Gray;
}

li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.active~li {
  background: lightblue;
}

.active~li::before {
  background: lightblue;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2em;
}

.table {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.row1 {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

.retransmission {
  background-color: #0;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffff99;
}

.row2 {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="ack_summary">Summary</h2>
<table style="width: 100%;">

  <tr>
    <th>Data/Ack Distribution - transfer 1, Packets 17 - 25</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <br>
      <ul class="bigger highlight-active">

        <li class="data">3</li>
        <li class="ack">3</li>

      </ul>
      <br>
      <h4>Cumulative Ack's distribution</h4>

      <div id="chartContainer121" class="chartContainer"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

*Edit*

In light of recent developments (as mentioned in the comments), rather declare the `z-index` property on the nested table cell tag, e.g:

```
td {
    z-index: 9;
    position: relative; /* required */
}
```

This way, any *nested element* will not be obscured by the containing element's `background-color` property. (expand updated code snippet below to observe this behaviour).

In addition, you can restore the negative `z-index` value initially declared on `li::before`.

```css
ul.bigger {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

ul.highlight-active li.active::before {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  background: green;
}

li.data {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: dodgerblue;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

li.ack {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: MediumSeaGreen;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

li::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: .9em;
  left: -4em;
  width: 4em;
  height: .2em;
  background: Gray;
  z-index: -1;
}


li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.active ~ li {
  background: lightblue;
}

.active ~ li::before {
  background: lightblue;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2em;
}

.table {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

.row1 {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

.retransmission {
    background-color: #0;
}
tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

tr:hover {background-color: #ffff99;}

.row2 {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

/* Additional */

td {
    z-index: 9;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="ack_summary">Summary</h2>
<table style="width: 100%;">

    <tr>
        <th>Data/Ack Distribution - transfer 1, Packets 17 - 25</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <br>
            <ul class="bigger highlight-active">
            
              <li class="data">3</li>
              <li class="ack">3</li>
              <li class="data">5</li>
              <li class="ack">2</li>
            
            </ul>
            <br>
            <h4>Cumulative Ack's distribution</h4>
            
            <div id="chartContainer121" class="chartContainer"></div>
            </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I'd recommend further reading to understand the *stacking context* and how this generally applies to the `z-index` property:

1. [Understanding CSS z-index - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index)
2. [z-index - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)
3. [The stacking context - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Comment: Spoke too soon. Yes it fixed the problem with 2 elements. When I added the third item to the list, I see the z-index now makes the line overlap to the next circle. Do you have an idea on how that can be fixed? I have updated the code in the code-pen https://codepen.io/bhaktaonline/pen/XzoVPr

Comment: @Bhakta0007 Answer updated to account for the new concerns you've just raised.

Comment: thanks so much for the quick turn-around. I can confirm it is working fine. Appreciate!