# CSS3 circles connected by smaller dots in between

Tags: html, css, sass

I really wanted to make 3 circles with smaller dots connecting them. I've been looking at this one
[Creating CSS3 Circles connected by lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642308/creating-css3-circles-connected-by-lines?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but what I need are smaller circles as separators. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code yourself? Or is this just a code writing request?

Comment: @TylerH Hello sir. The code I have is just the same as the link I provided above. I'm really just at a beginner level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Flexbox` and make space between circles responsive. You can also use `nth-child` selector to select every `5th` circle. [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/sra4o90h/6/)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.circle {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.big {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="circle big"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle big"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle big"></div>
</div>
```