# How to make a horizontal list of rings with text below

Tags: html, css, sass, html-lists

I'm trying to implement the following element using HTML/CSS:

[image: List with connected rings]

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to make the text appear below the rings. I've tried making the rings using SVG data URLs like this:

SVG:

```
<svg aria-hidden='true' focusable='false'>
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
```

Encoded using https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' aria-hidden='true' focusable='false'%3E%3Ccircle cx='25' cy='25' r='20' stroke='black' stroke-width='2' fill='transparent' /%3E%3C/svg%3E ");
```

I've looked at some examples and one of the closest is the Angular Material Stepper at https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/examples but I'm stumped as to how to even begin making this element.
As for the HTML, I think something along the lines of the following code snippet should be fine.

```html
<ul class="ratings">
    <li>Gering</li>
    <li>Mittel</li>
    <li class="active">Hoch</li>
    <li>Sehr hoch</li>
</ul>
```

For context, this is supposed to become a non-interactable display element in an Angular web-application. IE support isn't required at all so a solution using modern CSS (I'm using SCSS) would be perfectly fine.

I'd really appreciate if somebody more experienced with this kind of advanced CSS could give me some pointers on how to build this element. My last resort would be using rasterized graphics but the result would be considerably worse. Thanks in advance!

What I've tried so far:

- [Creating CSS3 Circles connected by lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642308/creating-css3-circles-connected-by-lines)
- https://dev.to/peterc/how-to-create-joined-bulletpoint-lists-with-css-bbc-news-style-1eem

Update:
My solution so far based on the selected answer:
https://jsfiddle.net/fkquce21/3/

Comment: use an SVG editor such as Inkscape to draw whatever SVG you want.

Comment: the SVG is not the primary problem, moreso the positioning of it using CSS

Comment: If you draw everything with SVG including the text why would positioning be a problem?

Comment: Ahh, well if I drew the whole thing in SVG that would theoretically work I guess... The problem then might be, how to integrate it with Angular to highlight the correct dot and make translatable texts. 
Edit: What's more, I wonder if assistive technologies would be able to handle that kind of element well to convey to the user what is being displayed. That's something more achievable in HTML.

Comment: SVG supports aria roles. Once you've drawn it you can add id values into the text you want to replace/modify and also add id values to the dots so you can highlight them.

Comment: That sounds useful but DOM manipulations are not really the way to go in Angular so I'd probably be producing a bit of a nightmare to maintain... Or do you know about a good way to integrate dynamic SVG in Angular?

Comment: There are lots of existing questions and answers on that. Are none of them helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are perhaps many different ways you could approach this, but strictly sticking to the HTML structure you've shared, I would use CSS to build my circles instead of SVG and position them this way:

```
.ratings {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}

.ratings:before {
  content: " ";
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.ratings li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.ratings li:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 5px;
  background: white;
}

.ratings li.active:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  background: black;
}
```

Here's a [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/det65cn7/75/) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try doing it the way you suggest. Will mark it as the answer if it ends up working out for me.

Comment: Glad if it helps. Let me know if you encounter any issues and need more help.

Comment: I was able to create a working static version based on this solution. Sadly, the line tends to overshoot the first and last element a bit if the content or container length is adjisted but I might be able to fix that using an element to cover it up.

Comment: @NiPfi I imagine 1. Giving `li` a fixed width and 2. Removing `margin` from `li` may also help make this more reliable. You may also want to eyeball the `width` value of `.ratings:before` according to your design. This is the same demo after I applied #1 and #2: https://jsfiddle.net/an4g6ytb/